# ARM DTS query for TI based SoC

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I am going through TI based evm dts file.

http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/dra7-evm.dts#L686

```
&atl {
      assigned-clocks =  <&abe_dpll_sys_clk_mux>,
                         <&atl_gfclk_mux>,
                         <&dpll_abe_ck>,
                         <&dpll_abe_m2x2_ck>,
                         <&atl_clkin2_ck>;
      assigned-clock-parents = <&sys_clkin2>, <&dpll_abe_m2_ck>;
      assigned-clock-rates = <0>, <0>, <180633600>, <361267200>, <5644800>;

      status = "okay";

      atl2 {
             bws = <DRA7_ATL_WS_MCASP2_FSX>;
             aws = <DRA7_ATL_WS_MCASP3_FSX>;
       };
};

 &mcasp3 {
           #sound-dai-cells = <0>;

            assigned-clocks = <&mcasp3_ahclkx_mux>;
            assigned-clock-parents = <&atl_clkin2_ck>;

            status = "okay";

            op-mode = <0>;          /* MCASP_IIS_MODE */
            tdm-slots = <2>;
            /* 4 serializer */
            serial-dir = <  /* 0: INACTIVE, 1: TX, 2: RX */
            1 2 0 0
            >;
            tx-num-evt = <32>;
            rx-num-evt = <32>;
 };
```

assigned-clocks contains a handle to <&mcasp3_ahclkx_mux> and this clock "&mcasp3_ahclkx_mux>" is defined in "dra7xx-clocks.dtsi"

http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/dra7xx-clocks.dtsi#L1814

But could not find how this" dra7xx-clocks.dtsi" has included into "dra7-evm.dtsi" ?

Can any please point me out how definition of mcasp3_ahclkx_mux is provided into dra7-evm.dts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But could not find how this" dra7xx-clocks.dtsi" has included into "dra7-evm.dtsi" ?

[dra7-evm.dts](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/dra7-evm.dts#L10) has included [dra74x.dtsi](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/dra74x.dtsi#L10) which includes [dra7.dtsi](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/dra7.dtsi#L2024), and [dra7xx-clocks.dtsi](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/dra7xx-clocks.dtsi) is included in [dra7.dtsi](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/dra7.dtsi#L2024) at the end.